# API json data to javascript variables

Tags: javascript, api

I have this problem, i have been trying 2 days to solve it.
My Javascript code:

```js
const request = require('request');

var req = {
  url: 'https://api.digitransit.fi/routing/v1/routers/hsl/index/graphql',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/graphql" },
  body: `{
    stop(id: "HSL:1122441") {
        stoptimesWithoutPatterns(numberOfDepartures: 1) {
        realtimeArrival,
        scheduledArrival,
        realtime,
        serviceDay,
        headsign,
      }
    }  
  }`
};

request(req, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, 4));
}
```

I want to get the data what the api sends back, into variables or somekind of thing, so i can call them anywhere in the script. The json data what comes back:

```
    {
    "data": {
        "stop": {
            "stoptimesWithoutPatterns": [
                {
                    "realtimeArrival": 60065,
                    "scheduledArrival": 60000,
                    "realtime": true,
                    "serviceDay": 1547676000,
                    "headsign": "Olympiaterminaali via Kallio"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

but when i use something about like this;

```
let stoptimesWithoutPatterns = body['stop'].stoptimesWithoutPatterns
```

it gives me error as

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'stoptimesWithoutPatterns' of undefined
```

As im very new to coding coding, i dont know very tehnical stuff. It would be cool if somebody could help me :) as i wanted to have my own website or app based around this if i can get this to work! Thank you!

Comment: `body.data.stop.stoptimesWithoutPatterns`

Comment: I can get stop data, it will display undefined, nothing more i know.

Comment: You're missing the `.data.` after `body`…!

Comment: Also, `body` is a string, right? You need to `JSON.parse` it and *then* access its `.data...`.

Comment: let stoptimesWithoutPatterns = Parsed.data.stop.stoptimesWithoutPatterns

TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined

Comment: So i have created a variable what stringifys and parses the data = Parsed

Comment: Please ensure that you've done `JSON.parse(body)` as @deceze mentioned. Then please `console.log(JSON.parse(body))` the output and add it to your post.

Comment: { data: { stop: { stoptimesWithoutPatterns: [Array] } } }

Answer (score 0):

By using this i accomplished what i wanted, thank you guys who commented! :) This gives me the value of realtimeArrival! :)

```
const request = require('request');

var req = {
  url: 'https://api.digitransit.fi/routing/v1/routers/hsl/index/graphql',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/graphql" },
  body: `{
    stop(id: "HSL:1122441") {
        stoptimesWithoutPatterns(numberOfDepartures: 1) {
        realtimeArrival,
        scheduledArrival,
        realtime,
        serviceDay,
        headsign,
      }
    }  
  }`
};

request(req, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    //console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, 4));
    let Parsed = JSON.parse(body);
    let stoptimesWithoutPatterns = Parsed.data.stop.stoptimesWithoutPatterns[0]['realtimeArrival'];
    console.log(stoptimesWithoutPatterns)
  }
});
```